# Encryption Decryption issue with Cipher in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Hi I am facing a decryption problem. The decrypted value is not matching the original one.

Here is my logic for `encryption` :

```
public byte[] encrypt(String plainText) {

    byte iv[] = new byte[ENCRYPTION_PARAM_SIZE];
    SecureRandom secRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secRandom.nextBytes(iv);
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_INSTANCE);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(fixSecret(encryptionKey), ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

And this is my logic for `Decryption`

```
public String decrypt(byte[] cipherText) {

    byte iv[] = new byte[ENCRYPTION_PARAM_SIZE];
    SecureRandom secRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secRandom.nextBytes(iv);
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_INSTANCE);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(fixSecret(encryptionKey), ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

}
```

Encryption options :

```
ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "DESede";
ENCRYPTION_INSTANCE = "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
Integer ENCRYPTION_PARAM_SIZE = 8;
```

This is how I am trying to verify :

```
public static void main(String[] args){    
    Long value = 9123456L;
    String strval = value.toString();
    byte[] encryptedVal = encrypt(strval);
    String decryptedVal = decrypt(encryptedVal);
    
    System.out.println("Original  value : " +strval);
    System.out.println("Encrypted value : " +encryptedVal.toString());
    System.out.println("Decrypted value : " +decryptedVal);
    System.out.println("Final     value : " +Long.parseLong(decryptedVal));
}
```

What I need to do here to make it work.

Note : The above code is working fine if I use the below logic without SecureRandom :

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[ENCRYPTION_PARAM_SIZE]));
```

Comment: *`fixSecret(encryptionKey)`* What happens here? You didn't post it

Comment: You use different IVs for encryption and decryption. To make decryption work, the IV applied for encryption must also be used for decryption. Usually the IV (which is not secret) is sent along with the ciphertext to the decryption side (typically concatenated).

Comment: Also note that your workaround is not a real solution, since a static IV (like a zero IV) is insecure.

Comment: @Topaco : How can I implement a dynamic IV here and make the encryption decryption work .. which is my main intention.

Comment: The IV is not meant to be a secret, so you can generate a new one using SecureRandom on encryption, then encrypt the data, then *prepend* the IV to the encrypted data and send this concatenated iv+encrypted date to the peer. The peer then strips off the IV and uses it for decryption.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, your issue is that the IV you are using for encryption is different than the one you are using for decryption. The IV is not sensitive (from a confidentiality point of view) so it can be transmitted alongside the ciphertext. Some applications prepend the IV to the ciphertext while others use more standard formats such as [CMS Encrypted Data](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652#section-8). Since you are using Java, you can generate CMS Encrypted Data structures using [Bouncy Castle's CMSEncryptedDataGenerator class](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSEncryptedDataGenerator.html).

There are two other issues with your code:

1. Choice of cryptographic primitives
2. Key management

**Cryptographic Primitives**

The cryptographic transformation you are using is "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding". Unless you have a good reason to use DES/3DES, you should consider switching to AES. Additionally, I would recommend using an [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) such as [AES-GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) or [AES-GCM-SIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES-GCM-SIV).

**Key Management**

All the cryptography in the world doesn't mean much if the keys aren't managed correctly. From your code it looks like you are constructing the SecretKeySpec object out of the key's bytes. If you can, try to use an hardware security module (HSM) or a key management system (KMS) where the key never gets exported from the tamper bounds of the device in plaintext format. AWS KMS, Azure Key Vault, and Google KMS all offer very affordable pricing for this. Of course, there are other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the decrypt function you generate a random Initialization Vector (IV), so this won't ever work.
You need to store the IV from the encrypt function and provide it as an input to the decrypt function.

Here's an example:

```
public byte[] encryptAndDecrypt(String plainText) {

  byte iv[] = new byte[ENCRYPTION_PARAM_SIZE];
  SecureRandom secRandom = new SecureRandom();
  secRandom.nextBytes(iv);

  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_INSTANCE);
  SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(fixSecret(encryptionKey), ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
  byte[] cipherText=cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  return decrypt(cipherText, iv)
}


public String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] iv) {

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_INSTANCE);
 SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(fixSecret(encryptionKey), ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
 return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
}
```

Note that by definition the IV should be random but shouldn't be treated as a secret so you can store it as plain data without any protection.
The idea behind the IV is to randomize the cipher text so if you're not using IV, or using a constant IV, and encrypt "X", cipher text is "Y", you could easily reverse the cipher text into plain text, while with random IV the cipher text is different every time.